# Change SKAudioNodes volume

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Hallo i try to change the volume of my SKAudioNode, does anyone know how to do that? I have tried to find a solution, but did not find one...
The AudioNode class seems pretty thin to me. I also can't access the nested Audio class to try further options from there on.

Answer (score 4):

Try this approach, running an action to change the volume.

```
OBJECT.runAction(SKAction.changeVolumeTo(Float(volume), duration: 0))
```

Comment: Hey this changes the hole volume, right? What i try to do is make one Audio Nodes volume smaller so, for a short amount of time the other Node is louder

Answer (score 3):

> Updated to Swift 4.0

I updated the code to `Swift 4.0`:

```
object.run(SKAction.changeVolume(to: Float(1), duration: 0))
```

This will save you a lot of time.